# How do I make that my hasura actions are ready to be used for my ci / cd tests?

Tags: graphql, action, hasura

I have started building up a backend with hasura. That backend is validated on my CI / CD service with api tests, among other things.

Within my hasura backend, I have implemented openfaas functions. I am deploying everything on a kubernetes cluster. Before running the tests, I wait until all jobs and all deployments are done. I am deploying with devspace which deploys everything through helm charts. So, at the end of the deployment, I am dead-sure the deployments are all done (ultimately, I've checked directly on the k8s cluster). Even the openfaas functions are deployed and ready to use.

Yet, when I run my acceptance tests, I run into issues. If I don't wait long enough, then my actions are not working properly. They return some strange errors that e.g. the response returned invalid json

```
Error: GraphQL error: not a valid json response from webhook
```

or the mutation is not in the mutation root

```
Error: GraphQL error: field "login" not found in type: 'mutation_root'
```

However, the openfaas functions themselves log only success. There is no error there. They are called and they apparently throw no error.

Waiting 3-5 minutes after hasura deployment or trying to call the actions until they return something relevant works fine, however. My current work-around is to wait an additional 5 minutes after my deployments have been done and only then run my api tests.

Is that normal? Is there a more efficient way to get feedback on when hasura really is ready to accept calls to its actions? I am currently working with version 1.2.1.

### EDIT

After re-verification, waiting "long enough" does not help. What, however, helps, is calling some actions until they return successful answer. Currently, what I am doing is

```sh
#! /bin/sh

if [ "$#" -lt "3" ] ; then
  echo "Usage: $0 <hasura-endpoint> <profile> <auth-app-id> [<timeout-in-sec> <deltat-in-sec>]"
  exit 1
fi

ENDPOINT=$1
PROFILE=$2
AUTH_APP_ID=$3
TIMEOUT=${4:-300}
DELTA_T=${5:-5}
FIXTURES_FILE=./shared/fixtures/${PROFILE}/database/Users/auth.json

username=$(jq -r '.[1].email' $FIXTURES_FILE)
password=$(jq -r '.[1].password' $FIXTURES_FILE)
user_id=$(jq -r '.[1].id' $FIXTURES_FILE)

echo "Trying to login with $username / $password / $AUTH_APP_ID"

for iteration in `seq 1 $TIMEOUT`; do
  result=$(gq $ENDPOINT -q 'mutation($username: String!, $password: String!, $appId: uuid!) { login(username: $username, password: $password, appId: $appId) { userId }}' -v "username=$username" -v "password=$password" -v "appId=$AUTH_APP_ID" | jq -r '.data.login.userId')
  if [ "$result" == "$user_id" ] ; then
    exit 0
  else
    sleep $DELTA_T
  fi
done

echo "Hasura actions availability timed out" && exit 1
```

That performs logins with valid credentials until the action returns the right user id, and not an error. The log of this script on my ci / cd is something like

```
$ ./scripts/login_until_it_works.sh ${API_ENDPOINT}/v1/graphql $PROFILE $AUTH_ADMIN_APP_ID
 Trying to login with nathalie.droz@test-vtxnet.ch / yl2YOuSrz_ / [MASKED]
 Executing query... error
 Error:  ApolloError: GraphQL error: not a valid json response from webhook
     at new ApolloError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/graphqurl/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:92:26)
     at Object.next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/graphqurl/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1297:31)
     at notifySubscription (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/graphqurl/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:135:18)
     at onNotify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/graphqurl/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:179:3)
     at SubscriptionObserver.next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/graphqurl/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:235:7)
     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/graphqurl/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1102:36
     at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
     at Object.next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/graphqurl/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1101:21)
     at notifySubscription (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/graphqurl/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:135:18)
     at onNotify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/graphqurl/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:179:3) {
   graphQLErrors: [
     {
       extensions: [Object],
       message: 'not a valid json response from webhook'
     }
   ],
   networkError: null,
   message: 'GraphQL error: not a valid json response from webhook',
   extraInfo: undefined
 }
 Executing query... done
```

Notice that the second query, 5 seconds after the first, is successful. My action is defined as follows:

```yaml
- args:
    enums: []
    input_objects: []
    objects:
    - description: null
      fields:
      - description: null
        name: token
        type: String!
      - description: null
        name: refreshToken
        type: String!
      - description: null
        name: userId
        type: uuid!
      name: LoginResponse
    scalars: []
  type: set_custom_types
- args:
    comment: null
    definition:
      arguments:
      - description: null
        name: username
        type: String!
      - description: null
        name: password
        type: String!
      - description: null
        name: appId
        type: uuid!
      forward_client_headers: false
      handler: http://gateway.openfaas:8080/function/login.{{FUNCTION_NAMESPACE}}
      headers: []
      kind: synchronous
      output_type: LoginResponse
      type: mutation
    name: login
  type: create_action
- args:
    action: login
    definition:
      select:
        filter: {}
    role: incognito
  type: create_action_permission
```

Comment: Coincidentally, I've started configuring the hasura JWT audience and now it's working all the time (apparently). I need to see if that continues, but since I have set the audience in the hasura JWT configuration string, my pipelines never fail because of the problem mentioned in my post above.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy via Helm, it creates the Deployments and everything else you've defined  and tells you it's done. That doesn't mean that whatever you deployed is ready to serve requests. That's because each service may have its own boot time, especially the services who advertise High Availability.

Kubernetes is designed to address this issue with the help of "liveness/readiness probes". Basically, in your yaml/helm files you instruct K8s what it needs to check before it returns that a pod is ready. This could be for example a 200 HTTP status code from `/live` endpoint in your app or whatever.

Check this out: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/

Comment: That's of course done in my case (cf. [this deployment.yaml file](https://gitlab.hidora.com/softozor/shopozor/services/-/blob/master/backend/database-service/chart/templates/deployment.yaml#L136)). The service is ready. The service's log files tell the service is ready, the liveness / readiness probes are green. I think it might be a bug of the hasura service. I'll try to narrow it down.